# Custom tailwind dropdown expanding parent container

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm building a custom dropdown using tailwindcss.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/TFzmx6DeAB

However, this dropdown expands its parent container, which is the white card.
How can I make so that, when its open, it doesnt expand its parent container?

I've tried by adding the relative class to the container... however i'm not that good at css...so maybe I'm doing it the wrong way, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try to add the `absolute` class to your dropdown `ul` element.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!